# Has anyone considered axioms to the effect that: "The axiom of constructibility fails very very badly?"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory

If I'm not mistaken, the axiom of constructibility basically says that the universe has no (non-trivial) inner models. Has anyone considered axioms of the opposite flavour, basically asserting that the universe has many inner models?

Apologies if I've misunderstood the axiom of constructibility, it is very confusing to me.

Comment: It seems to me you are looking for something like The Inner Model Hypothesis of Friedman's. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.7482&rep=rep1&type=pdf Someone else should be able to write a good answer on this. Not me.

Comment: @jolubo, thank you! Those three words "Inner Model Hypothesis" are exactly what I needed.

Comment: Yes, well, before you go berserk with googling three words, I'd suggest you have a good look at Asaf's answer once more. Then go berserk!

Comment: @jolubo, don't worry, I have learned many things from Asaf's answer (that is why I accepted it, after all).

Comment: But I think this is a very good question, and might get some attention on the MathOverflow site as well.

Comment: And in fact, even though Asaf's answer is very good, I don't think it answers your question, and it should not be accepted as it stands.

Comment: @jolubo, you're quite right in that Asaf didn't really answer the question. However, now that I have some reading material (thank you for that), I am quite happy to leave this question "closed" and "answered"; I will probably ask another, better posed question in the future once I know a little more. That being said, if someone were to come by and write a detailed answer about the inner model hypothesis or a similar axiom, then obviously I would give them the accepted answer mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axiom of constructibility is indeed equivalent to "there are no inner models", but this is not what it "essentially says". This would be sort of a backwards way of understanding the axiom.

Instead the axiom says that we can find a hierarchy where every set appears in some stage, and it is first-order definable over the previous stage in the hierarchy. In contrast, when we consider the von Neumann we take **all** the subsets of the previous step, definable or not.

It turns out that two models with the same ordinals have the same constructible universe. So in turn it follows that the axiom $V=L$ is equivalent to saying that there is no inner model (note, however, that "there are no inner models" is not a first-order statement).

If anything is the opposite of $V=L$ it would be the existence of $0^\#$. This axiom implies that not only $V\neq L$, but it is in fact *very* far away from $L$. What does that mean? If we start with $L$ and we add using forcing a real number, or even a proper class of new sets, then the resulting model will be somewhat close to $L$. In what sense do we mean close? If $X$ is any uncountable set of ordinals, then there is some $Y\in L$ which is a set of ordinals, $X\subseteq Y$ and $|X|=|Y|$. This is known as the covering lemma.

The existence of $0^\#$ is equivalent to saying that the covering lemma fails, and it turns out that it fails in many many places, when it fails. For example the set $\{\aleph_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ cannot be covered by any set of size $<\aleph_\omega$ which is in $L$. The reason is that $\aleph_\omega$ is regular in $L$, so any unbounded subset must have size $\aleph_\omega$.

If you want to extend this further, there is the notion of relative constructibility which says that there is some set $A$ from which the universe is constructible. And so we can define the notion of $A^\#$ in a similar fashion.

So the "ultimate anti-$L$ axiom" would be something of the form $\forall A(V\neq L[A])$. This axiom is a consequence of large cardinals such as strongly compact cardinals (and in fact much much weaker than that). And these axioms are used on a regular basis in set theory.

Comment: Woah. You're quick.

Comment: Would be faster, but my tablet can only process so many words (the times I had to stop writing and wait for the buffers to clear up was uncountable on a single hand; this is also necessary since the keyboard is not optimal and typos are inevitable).

Comment: As great as mathematics is, you need to leave math and become a typist. **The world needs you.**

Comment: If only I could have taken my Unicomp keyboard with me everywhere... *sigh*

Comment: Wait $\aleph_\omega$ is regular in $L$? I thought $L$ satisfied ZFC, which would suggest that $\aleph_\omega$ is singular.

Comment: Yes, but $V$ and $L$ disagree about which cardinal is $\aleph_\omega$. In fact every uncountable cardinal in $V$ is inaccessible (and much much more) in $L$.

Comment: Right. So *if* $0^{\sharp}$ exists, then every $\kappa > \aleph_0$ is believed inaccessible by $L.$ But if $V=L$ holds, then $L$ has the same opinions as $V$, because they're "equal." Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but it's actually more than that. If $0^\#$ exists, then $L$ and $V$ disagree on the successor of every singular cardinal. If it doesn't exist, then they will never disagree (granted $V$ thinks that it is a cardinal, of course if you collapse $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ to be countable then $V$ and $L$ will disagree on the successor of $(\aleph_\omega)^L$, but $V$ will disagree it is a cardinal to begin with.)

Comment: I take it that merely assuming that for every ordinal $\alpha$ we have "$L$ thinks that $\aleph_\alpha$ is inaccessible" is insufficient to prove the existence of $0^\sharp$?

Comment: @user18921: Well, if $\alpha$ allowed to be $\omega$, or any other singular cardinal, then it is sufficient. If you just mean $\alpha+1$, instead then the answer is no. We can start with a class of inaccessible cardinals (which is a very weak assumption) and collapse them (over $L$) so the $\alpha$-th inaccessible is $\aleph_\alpha$. But we only get that regular cardinals in the extension are inaccessible in $L$, not that *every* cardinal is inaccessible.